# Dynamic Control Name Access

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with inputs created dynamically. Their names are generated like
`newpackqty1`, `newpackqty2`, `newpackqty3`, and so on.

I am trying to validate that at least on of these controls has value. This is my code:

```
for (let i = 1; i <= parseInt(lblCount.value); i++) {
  let newqty = 'newpackqty' + i.toString();
  if ($("input[name=newqty]").val() == 0) {
    noSrcLabels = true;
    break;
  }
```

Comment: Do you have any control over how the inputs are created?  Can you give them all the same class?  Can you wrap them in a div (with a class)?  Are they all the same input type (eg number)?

Comment: Looks like you need to change `$("input[name=newqty]")` to `$("input[name=" + newqty + "]")`

Comment: Also, your logic is slight around the wrong way - set `noSrcLabels = true` at the start, then if any `.val() > 0` set `noSrcLabels=false`  to check if at least one has a value (but you might find it easier not to use a "negative" variable name, eg use `hasSrcLabels`, initially false then set to true when one found.

Comment: $("input[name=" + newqty + "]") That did the trick thanks very much.